# Remove a node from XML file in MS Project VBA

Tags: xml, vba, ms-project

I’d like to remove a node from my xml file using **VBA in MS Project 2007**.

Should be so easy but I can’t get it running.

**Here is my XML**

```
<config id="config" ConfigSaveDate="2011-03-31 21:32:55" ConfigSchemaVersion="1.02">
    <Custom> 
    </Custom>
    <Program>
      <DateFormat>yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss</DateFormat> 
    </Program>
    <ProjectFile ProjectFileName="projectfile1.mpp">
      <RevisionNumber>201</RevisionNumber> 
      <FileName>projectfile1.mpp</FileName> 
      <LastSaveDate>2011-03-23 16:45:19</LastSaveDate> 
    </ProjectFile>
    <ProjectFile ProjectFileName="projectfile2bedeleted.mpp">
      <RevisionNumber>115</RevisionNumber> 
      <FileName>projectfile2bedeleted.mpp</FileName> 
      <LastSaveDate>2011-03-31 21:12:55</LastSaveDate> 
    </ProjectFile>
    <ProjectFile ProjectFileName="projectfile2.mpp">
      <RevisionNumber>315</RevisionNumber> 
      <FileName>projectfile2.mpp</FileName> 
      <LastSaveDate>2011-03-31 21:32:55</LastSaveDate> 
    </ProjectFile>
</config>
```

**Here is my VBA code**

```
Function configProjListDelete(configPath As String, ProjFiles As Variant) As Integer

  ' This function shall delete <ProjectFile> tags from the config.xml
  ' and shall delete coresponding project xml files from HD
  ' It shall return number of deleted files

  ' configPath is the  path to the xml folder
  ' ProjFiles is an array of file names of to be deleted files in above mentioned folder

  Dim xml As MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Dim RootElem As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
  'Dim cxp1 As CustomXMLPart
  Dim delNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode ' XmlNode 'MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
  Dim fSuccess As Boolean
  Dim ProjectFileList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
  Dim fn As Variant 'file name in loop
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim delCnt As Integer

  If Not FileExists(configPath) Then
    ' given configFile doesn't exist return nothing
    Debug.Print "  iven config file doesn't exist. File: " & configPath
    GoTo ExitconfigProjListDelete
  End If

  'TODO: Catch empty ProjectFiles

  ' Initialize variables
  Set xml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

  On Error GoTo HandleErr
  ' Load the  XML from disk, without validating it.
  ' Wait for the load to finish before proceeding.
  xml.async = False
  xml.validateOnParse = False
  fSuccess = xml.Load(configPath)
  On Error GoTo 0
  ' If anything went wrong, quit now.
  If Not fSuccess Then
    GoTo ExitconfigProjListDelete
  End If

  Set RootElem = xml.DocumentElement

  Debug.Print "- " & xml.getElementsByTagName("ProjectFile").Length & " ProjectFiles in config."

  i = 0
  delCnt = 0
  ' Loop through all ProjectFiles
  For Each ProjectFileList In xml.getElementsByTagName("ProjectFile")

    ' check if each project file name is one of the files to be deleted
    For Each fn In ProjFiles
      If fn = ProjectFileList.getElementsByTagName("FileName").NextNode.nodeTypedValue Then
        Debug.Print fn & " shall be deleted"

        ' remove it from the document

        ' here I'm struggeling!
        '#################################################
        ' How to delete the node <ProjectFile> and its childNodes?
        Set delNode = ProjectFileList.ParentNode
        xml.DocumentElement.RemoveChild (ProjectFileList) ' Error: 438 rough translation: "Object doesn't support this methode"

        ' This is all I've tried, but nothing works
        '===========================================
        'RootElem.RemoveChild (delNode)
        'xml.RemoveChild (delNode)
        'RootElem.RemoveChild (ProjectFileList.SelectSingleNode("ProjectFile"))
        'ProjectFileList.ParentNode.RemoveChild (ProjectFileList.ChildNodes(0))

        'Set objParent = datenode.ParentNode
        'xmldoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild (objParent)

        'Set ProjectFileList = Empty


        delCnt = delCnt + 1
      End If
    Next fn

    i = i + 1
  Next ProjectFileList

  ' Save XML File
  If checkAppPath("Trying to update config file.") Then
    xml.Save CustomProperty("XMTMLMonitoring_AppPath") & "\" & m2w_config("SubFolder") & "\" & m2w_config("SubFolderData") & "\" & m2w_config("XMLConfigFileName")
    Debug.Print "  - Config has been updated and saved."
  Else
    MsgBox "Config data not exported to web." & Chr(10) & "Folder: '" & CustomProperty("XMTMLMonitoring_AppPath") & "\" & m2w_config("SubFolder") & "\" & m2w_config("SubFolderData") & Chr(10) & "doesn't exist. ", vbOKOnly, HEADLINE
  End If

  Set xml = Nothing

  configProjListDelete = delCnt

ExitconfigProjListDelete:
Exit Function

HandleErr:
  Debug.Print "XML File reading error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.DESCRIPTION
  MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.DESCRIPTION
  On Error GoTo 0


End Function
```

I’d be glad to get some help!

Comment: FYI, it would help if you could just give us the relevant parts of your code and format it so we don't have to scroll 4 screens down and to the right to see the whole thing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you know about [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp)? From the painful looks of your code, you do not. Instead of using a long combination of barbaric DOM methods to access the node you need, you should save yourself a lot of pain and just use an XPath to access it in one line.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, then something like the following can replace your entire double loop, from `i=0` to `Next ProjectFileList`:

```
For i = LBound(ProjFiles) To UBound(ProjFiles)
    Set deleteMe = XML.selectSingleNode( _
        "/config/ProjectFile[@ProjectFileName='" & ProjFiles(i) & "']")
    Set oldChild = deleteMe.parentNode.removeChild(deleteMe)
Next i
```

where the thing in "quotes" is an XPath. Hope this helps.

As a side note, it seems inefficient, confusing, and error-prone to have a `ProjectFileName` attribute and a `FileName` element containing the exact same information in your XML file. What's up with that?

Comment: +1 Note, however, that the original code in the question is (perhaps unintentionally) using the older MSXML, v3.0 which does not use XPath as its default query language - it uses XSLPatterns instead. Specifying `DOMDocument` is the same as specifying `DOMDocument30`. Suggest that changing this to `DOMDocument60` to use MSXML, v6.0 would be beneficial as XPath would then be the default query language. Alternatively you can set MSXML, v3.0 to use XPath - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx

Comment: Good point! This had slipped my attention.

Comment: Hello Jean,
It works great! I'll tidy up my code and I’ll review the XML schema.
Pain is the right word!  It is terrible. So you did not only help me with my problem – you pushed me far ahead! 
Thanks a lot!